# How is the number of representatives within EU structures computed?

Tags: european-union

This rather old [article](https://www.euractiv.com/section/future-eu/news/eu-countries-ranked-for-influence-potential/) argues about EU countries actual influence within the EU:

> Germany is over-represented in the European Parliament, giving it a
>   correspondingly high potential to influence EU policies, while other
>   countries are at disadvantage, according to a recent report by a
>   Romanian think-tank. EURACTIV Romania reports.
>
> Qvorum, a non-partisan think-tank which aims to stimulate citizens’
>   and social partners’ involvement in the policymaking process,
>   discovered that a number of countries have won privileged
>   representation in the assembly’s governing bodies, while other nations
>   are clearly under-represented.

Ten years have passed and I expect things to have changed. I am wondering if there is a more recent influence related article.

However, I am mainly interested in the causes of this difference in "influence". I expect that some objective facts such as population or GDP to be an important factor in influencing the number of representatives within an EU structure.

**Question:** How is number of representatives within EU structures computed?

Comment: @DenisdeBernardy - this covers the EU Parliament only, but it provides a great insight. So, one should expect that some countries having greater "influence" in EU politics "by design".

Comment: Why "over-represented"? Only because germany has more seats than each other country? I (as a german) am **under-represented** because german citizens have less representatives per inhabitants. The EU parliament ist not some sort of senate.

Comment: The question does not make it clear, and all answerers so far have missed, that this _is not about_ allocation of seats.  It is about which countries have the most committee chairpeople, presidents/vice-presidents, party leaders, parliamentary officers, and so forth.  It's a rather unusual way of looking at things, as one usually looks at which _political parties_ have the the most committee chairpeople, presidents/vice-presidents, parliamentary officers, and so forth.

Comment: @Alexei A study from a Danish Think-Tank just came out that relates somewhat with the subject you've cited from the Romanian Think-Tank. I've added what I felt was the relevant information in my answer but you can find the paper here: [Who is big in Brussels?](http://english.thinkeuropa.dk/politics/who-big-brussels).

Comment: @armatita - this is very interesting and much more recent, so more relevant. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Note**: you can see **Article 15** of the [TEU](https://www.consilium.europa.eu/en/european-council/members/) for the European Council, **Article 19** for the Court of Justice, and different sections of the [TFEU](https://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/?uri=celex%3A12012E%2FTXT) for the European Central Bank and the Court of Auditors. It's fairly straightforward since it mostly requires a representative by member plus a president (or other similar positions). As so I'll focus on this answer on the EU parliament which has more complex (and "flexible") rules.

---

The allocation ([apportionment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apportionment_(politics))) of seats in the EU parliament is decided by treaty following the rules exposed in Article 14 of the [Treaty on European Union](https://eur-lex.europa.eu/resource.html?uri=cellar:2bf140bf-a3f8-4ab2-b506-fd71826e6da6.0023.02/DOC_1&format=PDF). Furthermore the actual composition is decided by the [European Council](https://www.consilium.europa.eu/en/european-council/).

> **Article 14**
>
> 1. The European Parliament shall, jointly with the Council, exercise legislative and budgetary functions. It shall exercise functions of
>      political control and consultation as laid down in the Treaties. It
>      shall elect the President of the Commission.
> 2. The European Parliament shall be composed of representatives of the Union's citizens. They shall not exceed seven hundred and fifty in
>      number, plus the President. Representation of citizens shall be
>      **degressively proportional**, with a minimum threshold of six members per
>      Member State. No Member State shall be allocated more than ninety-six
>      seats. **The European Council shall adopt by unanimity, on the**
>      **initiative of the European Parliament and with its consent, a decision**
>      **establishing the composition of the European Parliament**, respecting
>      the principles referred to in the first subparagraph.
> 3. The members of the European Parliament shall be elected for a term of five years by direct universal suffrage in a free and secret
>      ballot.
> 4. The European Parliament shall elect its President and its officers from among its members.

To give a more practical example. Last year the [European Council decided on the new rules of the parliament composition](https://www.consilium.europa.eu/en/press/press-releases/2018/06/29/the-european-council-establishes-the-composition-of-the-european-parliament/) after the UK left the EU. The [rules they choose are these](http://data.consilium.europa.eu/doc/document/ST-7-2018-REV-1/en/pdf):

> **Article 1**
>
> In the application of Article 14(2) TEU, the following principles
>   shall be respected:
>
> – the allocation of seats in the European Parliament is to fully
>   utilise the minimum and maximum thresholds per Member State set by the
>   TEU in order to reflect as closely as possible the sizes of the
>   respective populations of the Member States,
>
> – degressive proportionality is to be defined as follows: **the ratio
>   between the population and the number of seats of each Member State
>   before rounding to whole numbers is to vary in relation to their
>   respective populations in such a way that each Member of the European
>   Parliament from a more populous Member State represents more citizens
>   than each Member of the European Parliament from a less populous
>   Member State and, conversely, that the larger the population of a
>   Member State, the greater its entitlement to a large number of seats
>   in the European Parliament,**
>
> – the allocation of seats in the European Parliament is to reflect
>   demographic developments in the Member States

Just as a curiosity this would be the [new allocation of seats in the EU parliament](http://www.europarl.europa.eu/news/en/headlines/eu-affairs/20180126STO94114/eu-elections-how-many-meps-will-each-country-get-in-2019).

**NOTE: this will likely not be followed considering the latest developments on Brexit. It's in this answer for illustration purposes only.**

[image]

---

**EDIT:** In the web page [EU institutions and bodies in brief](https://europa.eu/european-union/about-eu/institutions-bodies_en) you'll find the list of the several institutions within the EU. Some of those only have sparse influence on policy. I will not describe the selection process for all of those bodies but that document should put you on the right track should you wish to do so. Most of this answer will focus instead on the EU parliament with pointers to other EU major institutions.

In any case the list of bodies and institutions is the following:

> - European Parliament
> - European Council
> - Council of the European Union
> - European Commission
> - Court of Justice of the European Union (CJEU)
> - European Central Bank (ECB)
> - European Court of Auditors (ECA)
> - European External Action Service (EEAS)
> - European Economic and Social Committee (EESC)
> - European Committee of the Regions (CoR)
> - European Investment Bank (EIB)
> - European Ombudsman
> - European Data Protection Supervisor (EDPS)
> - Interinstitutional bodies

For legislation (which I believe are the more relevant to your question since it directly relates to policy):

> **Law-making** There are 3 main institutions involved in EU legislation:
>
> - the **European Parliament**, which represents the EU’s citizens and is directly elected by them;
> - the **Council of the European Union**, which represents the governments of the individual member countries. The Presidency of the Council is
>     shared by the member states on a rotating basis.
> - the **European Commission**, which represents the interests of the Union as a whole.

For administration:

> Two other institutions play vital roles:
>
> - the **Court of Justice** of the EU upholds the rule of European law
> - the **Court of Auditors** checks the financing of the EU's activities.

Interinstitutional bodies:

> The EU has a number of other institutions and interinstitutional
>   bodies that play specialised roles:
>
> - the **European Central Bank** is responsible for European monetary policy
> - the **European External Action Service** (EEAS) assists the High Representative of the Union for Foreign Affairs and Security Policy,
>     currently Federica Mogherini. She chairs the Foreign Affairs Council
>     and conducts the common foreign and security policy, also ensuring the
>     consistency and coordination of the EU's external action.
> - the **European Economic and Social Committee** represents civil society, employers and employees
> - the **European Committee of the Regions** represents regional and local authorities
> - the **European Investment Bank** finances EU investment projects and helps small businesses through the European Investment Fund
> - the **European Ombudsman investigates** complaints about maladministration by EU institutions and bodies
> - the **European Data Protection Supervisor** safeguards the privacy of people’s personal data
> - the **Publications Office** publishes information about the EU
> - the **European Personnel Selection Office** recruits staff for the EU institutions and other bodies
> - the **European School of Administration** provides training in specific areas for members of EU staff
> - a host of specialised agencies and decentralised bodies handle a range of technical, scientific and management tasks

Furthermore you have positions related to smaller offices, or within EU political parties (which keep coming and going and almost certainly chose their own rules of selection).

---

**EDIT (3, May, 2019): Regarding the influence of different members in the EU**

Today a study reported by [EUobserver](https://euobserver.com/institutional/144787?utm_source=euobs&utm_medium=email) and made by a [Danish Europe Think Tank](http://english.thinkeuropa.dk/politics/who-big-brussels) analyses the influence of EU members. The paper is named [WHO IS BIG IN BRUSSELS?](http://english.thinkeuropa.dk/sites/english.thinkeuropa.dk/files/paper_who_is_big_in_brussels.pdf):

> *RESUME* How  come    some    small   member  states  in  the EU  have    more    influence   over
>   policy-making than    their   size    suggests    they    should  have?   This    informal    fact    of  EUcooperation   is  repeatedly  insinuated  by  expert   observers,  surveys     and scorecards,
>   such  as  those   by  the European    Council on  Foreign Relations.  Here,   Sweden  and the Netherlands,    for instance,   are believed    to  have    more    influence   than    more    populous
>   countries such    as  Italy   or  Romania.    While   the Franco-German   duo may be  the EU’s
>   undisputed    powerhouse, there   is  no  linear  relationship    between size    and influence
>   over  EU  policy  among   the smaller member  states.

I cannot fully subscribe to their methodology (the name of the paper might be bigger in scope than the study) but there are some interesting pointers. For example, and although France and Germany are by far the largest members, the staff number does not correlate totally with size with some small countries having large representations:

[image: EU staff by member]

Moreover they also built a map of the countries they consider over-represented, and under-represented:

[image: EU representation by member (map)]

Last but not least they make an analysis about the capacity of different members doing coalitions to achieve some objective in the EU:

> The   ECFR    finds   that    Germany and France  are more    effective   at  building    coalitions  than    any other   member  state.  While   they    are assisted    by  their   great   size    in  sustaining  a    widespread  perception  within  the     Union   that  they  are the most    important  partners    in  integration initiatives,     the     think  tank    also    notes    that   France  and Germany’s coalition building    success is  due to  their   uniquely    high    levels  of  interaction with    their   EU  allies. This    is  a   variable    that    is  linked  to  the availability    of  resources   at  the perm-reps,  and here    Germany and France  are by  far the biggest in  our survey.
>
> In    a   similar vein    we  may speculate   that    staff   numbers also    contribute  to  explain the ECFR’s
>   findings  that,   among   the Nordic  trio    in  the EU, Denmark,    Finland and Sweden, Sweden  contacts    Finland much    more    ‘on European    policy  matters’    than    it  contacts    Denmark,    and Finland contacts    Sweden, the Netherlands and Estonia more    than    it  contacts    Denmark.    While   Denmark’s   influence   may be  lower   than    its neighbours  due to  its EU-opt-outs (on justice and home    affairs,    defence and the euro),  it  may also    be  part    of  the story   that    out of  these   countries,  the Danish  permrep is  the only    one to  rank    below   its population  rank.   At  least,  its relatively  small   permanent   representation, and short   duration    of  secondments from    most    home    ministries, do  nothing to  alleviate   the possible    loss    of  influence   from    the opt-outs    that    Denmark may be  experiencing.   In  this    respect,    it  is  noteworthy  from    our figures that    especially  Slovenia    appears to  try to  compensate  for its small   mission in  Brussels by  prioritising    the     presence    of  home   ministry     staff   and     by ensuring     a  longer  duration    of  secondments.

Comment: This doesn't address the question though.  It's not representation in parliament, but representation in "EU structures".  That is to say, committees and government agencies.  The claim is that Germany has more representation in leading such "structures" than their population would warrant.  This becomes clearer if you read the linked article.

Comment: @Brythan In the first paragraph of the answer I comment and link the documents that describe how the representatives for several of the EU "structures" are selected (TEU and TFEU), including some of the articles. Given the complexity of the selection for EU parliament I decide to focus on that. The article only vaguely explains how the Romanian think thank calculated its ranking. I would have to speculate and guess a lot to answer the question under those circumstances. Given the title question I would say my answer is adequate. But I'll add further documentation regarding other EU bodies.

Comment: You're still missing the point.  The claim isn't that Germany has more representatives in parliament than its share of the population.  The claim is that it has more leadership roles in parliament than its share of the population.  How are those leadership roles selected?  Consider this statement about the US:  "California is overrepresented in House leadership positions."  In that case, the explanation is that leadership positions are awarded by seniority and California has an unusually high share of highly partisan districts that send only Democrats to the House.

Comment: @Brythan Very well. You apparently completely understood the question so please clarify me. What "leadership roles" exactly is the OP asking for? And for what institutions? I would also recommend changing the title question (and body, and tags) to accurately reflect that this question is in fact about the influence of Germany or any other members in EU "structures" (which I assumed were the big influential institutions, but I guess it can also be the communication manager of their Facebook page).

Comment: The last edit points to a study that tackles the exact issue I was looking for.

Comment: I think this needs splitting into two answers. Or at least the first part (Original Answer) about the make up of the MEP seats taking out, now that we've cleared up what the question actually was.

Answer (score 5):

For the EC and the ECJ, the rule is straightforward: it's one appointment per member state.

[For the EP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apportionment_in_the_European_Parliament), the general idea is to give similar representation to each country based on their population, with two twists:

- Early on, smaller countries got a few bonus seats so larger countries (Germany, France, Italy at the time) couldn't simply band together and push them around. These bonus seats stuck around over time. (This is similar in spirit to [what the Bundesrat does](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bundesrat_of_Germany#Today) and it is called [degressive proportionality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degressive_proportionality).)
- For political reasons, countries of similar size have traditionally been given the same number of seats. For instance France, Italy, and the UK (until 2014, when France got a bonus seat); or Spain and Poland; and so forth.

As to who chairs committees and the like, which is what the article seems to be looking at, what the whining is about beggars belief. The US equivalent would be to complain that CA, NY, FL, and TX are overrepresented in the US House. But that should come as no surprise given that they've more Reps to begin with. Who gets what seat in EP committees and such depends on how the MEPs want to manage their sausage factory. It simply happens that, as the most populous EU member, Germany also has the most MEPs. And in contrast with the UK and France for instance, they don't have a large swath of EU skeptics in a parliament controlled by a non-extremist coalition.

Comment: Note that this correctly implies that large countries are *under*represented on a vote per capita basis, in contrast to the quote in the original question.

Comment: its the Bundesrat not the Bundestag which got the fixed baseline amount per seats rule. (source: being from germany)

Comment: This doesn't address the question though.  It's not representation in parliament, but representation in "EU structures".  That is to say, committees and government agencies.  The claim is that Germany has more representation in leading such "structures" than their population would warrant.  This becomes clearer if you read the linked article.

Comment: @Brythan: I'm not sure I agree. The article's first sentence is "Germany is over-represented in the European Parliament" -- which is silly if you look at the number of representatives. And if one looks at who chairs committees and the like, as the article seems to have done, it's akin to saying CA, NY, FL, and TX are overrepresented in the US House. That only depends on the MEPs themselves, and it should come as no surprise given that they've more MEPs to begin with.